# Determining the issue regarding python versions for running repo init

Tags: python, android, git, repo

When I am using `repo init` to initialize some repo from a source, I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/workspace/.repo/repo/main.py", line 56, in <module>
    from subcmds.version import Version
  File "/home/workspace/.repo/repo/subcmds/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    ['%s' % name])
  File "/home/workspace/.repo/repo/subcmds/upload.py", line 27, in <module>
    from hooks import RepoHook
  File "/home/workspace/.repo/repo/hooks.py", line 472
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The following are the python versions I have:

```
python -V -> 2.7
python3 -V -> 3.6
```

According to [this](https://github.com/Iolaum/git-repo/blob/e7379dc5f75f4c331c16b4199904dc98ee858e5f/docs/python-support.md) link, python 3.6 is required starting with repo-1.14 but I'm not certain if that's what my repo version is - didn't have any luck finding a way around determining the version.

Comment: Try `grep '^VERSION' $(which repo)` in bash.

Comment: it says `(1, 22)`. What does that mean? 1.22?

Comment: It means the version of the repo launcher is 1.22. Can `repo version` work?

Comment: nope. it returns the same error as I posted in the description

Comment: `repo version` prints the repo version and the repo launcher version. The repo launcher is `which repo` and it's 1.22 in your case. The repo version is the output of the command `git describe` in `/home/workspace/.repo/repo`.

Comment: right so I'm using 1.22 which requires python 3.6+ version. Do you see why it would fail still despite having python3.6+?

Comment: I'm struggling with a similar issue. it appears to be launching your 2.7 version. after removing 2.7 it no longer threw this error. however now it is saying that it cant find python. I think I have an issue with my python 3 install.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are running an old repo launcher script version that is incompatible with the latest repo version. To fix this, download the latest repo launcher python script from Google and replace your outdated one.

The launcher script is the executable python script called "repo" and is located in your PATH, usually `~/bin` ([according to Google's instructions](https://source.android.com/setup/develop#installing-repo)) or `~/.local/bin/`. To find out where yours is located, type `which repo` in the terminal and it will print the script's location.

Let's say your repo script is in ~/bin. To download the script (and make it executable), you can do:

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
```

Also, you do not need to remove Python 2.7 for repo to work. I use Ubuntu 18.04 and have both Python 2.7 and 3.6 installed as well, and repo runs fine.